# Save array with multiple columns to csv

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multilabel-classification

If i write like this i get the csv file i want

```
a = asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

but the problem is that for getting the values I have something similar to this:

```
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(3):
        e = get_val(i)  # so I get 1,2,3; next loop 4,5,6 and third 7,8,9
```

So I tried to make the array in the format I needed by using append but it
seems I get

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

So does anyone know how to have the array in the required format?

Note: the input in the real app I'm working in is the skeleton point in `openpose`

Comment: If you want help clean up the formaatting.  Show what you need and what you get,

Comment: yes u are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this backwards. Suppose we have this linear list `a`, we can make
that into a `numpy` array as follows. This would allow you to use your function
`get_val` instead.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = []
for j in range(3):
    b2 = []
    for i in range(3):
        e =  a[3*j+i] # get_val(i)
        b2.append(e)
    b.append(b2)
print(np.asarray(b))
# [[1 2 3]
# [4 5 6]
# [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to nest two loops, something like this:

```
a = []
n = 1
for j in range(1,4):
    b = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        b.append(n)
        n += 1
    a.append(b)
print(a)
```

You're on the right track, but need to initialize two lists. The inner list, let's call it b, needs to be reinitialized at the beginning of every outer loop, or it will keep growing to 6 and then 9 items long.

Comment: No problem! Would you mind marking it answered, and upvote useful?